# Reading existing file to process data in c

Tags: c, dictionary

I have modified an existing code from `

> https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/lexicographical-order

The modification is done to read from existing pointer to array. However, I kept getting signs output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqWBb.jpg

```
    char *s1, *st1;
    int i, j;
    char arr[10][10], temp[50];

        s1 = strtok(str1, ";");
        do
        {
            st7 = strstr(s1, "s__");
            if (st7 != NULL)
            {
                for (i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
                {
                    for (j = i + 1; st7[j] < 10; ++j)
                    {                           
                        if(strcmp(arr[st7[i]], arr[st7[j]]) > 0)
                        {
                            strcpy(temp, arr[st7[i]]);
                            strcpy(arr[st7[i]], arr[st7[j]]);
                            strcpy(arr[st7[j]], temp);
                        }                           
                    }
                }
                printf("%s\n", arr[i]);     
            }           
        } while (s1 = strtok(NULL, ";"));
```

s1: To separate the strings

st7: To select the substring from the string (main result)

**str1: It is initialized via the substring of the main file(which I used fopen)** The result contain names starting with eg: k__hi, s__bye

The modification is done to organise the strings in dictionary order while getting the strings from st7[selected substrings from a string(s1)].

Please advise as I am new to c programming :)

Comment: You need to show how `str1` and `arr` are initialized, i.e. what they contain when this code is executed.

Comment: `st7` will point to a string that has the form "s__??????". It seems strange that you use characters like `s` and `_` for indexing `arr`.

Comment: You still need to show `arr` is defined and initialized..

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Read also the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* function that you are using. For your next question, provide some [MCVE] please. StackOverflow is *not* a "debug-my-code" site

Comment: Hi,I have edited the area you have asked. p.s: Sorry if the code is slightly unclear as I have picked out the main function of the code,as my code is quite long 

@4386427

Comment: You probably should use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), and you may want to use [string functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and, if you have them, [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). Don't forget to `free` dynamically allocated memory at the appropriate time and place.

Comment: The arr is defined only in the for loop same as the code in the hyperlink suggested.Hence,i am only just modifying the code. Instead of getting the user to key in the names, I allow the program to read through the names via pointer as the names are already stored in an existing file. @4386427

Comment: Avoid [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)s, [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other kind of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

If `str1` points to the string "k__hi, s__bye" then `st7` points to "s__bye". So when you do

```
if(strcmp(arr[st7[i]], arr[st7[j]]) > 0)
```

with `i` equal 0 and `j` equal 1, you do:

```
if(strcmp(arr[st7[0]], arr[st7[1]]) > 0)
```

since `st7` points to the string "s__bye", it is the same as

```
if(strcmp(arr['s'], arr['_']) > 0)
```

Using `'s'` and `'_'` as array index is **not** what you want as the array is defined as `arr[10][10]`, i.e. the valid index is 0 to 9 and `'s'` is more than 10. In other words - your access is outside the array and therefore the code has undefined behavior.

Further the `arr` is uninitialized so you are not comparing any valid data. Once again this is undefined behavior.

So you need to do two things:

1) Initialize the array

2) Fix the index so that it's always in the range 0..9

It's a bit unclear what you are trying but I guess that you should copy the string pointed to by `st7` into the array and then sort the array. Perhaps like:

```
        if (st7 != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(arr[0], st7);  // Not sure which index to use here
                                  // So I just used index 0

            for (i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
                {                           
                    if(strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) > 0)  // Only use i and j for indexing
                    {
                        strcpy(temp, arr[i]);
                        strcpy(arr[i], arr[j]);
                        strcpy(arr[j], temp);
                    }                           
                }
                printf("%s\n", arr[i]);     // Moved inside the loop
            }
        }
```

Putting it all together in an example with 4 words could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_WORDS 4
char arr[NUM_WORDS][50];

void add_word(char* str1)
{
    char *s1, *st1, *st7;
    int i, j;
    char temp[50];

    s1 = strtok(str1, ";");
    do
    {
        st7 = strstr(s1, "s__");
        if (st7 != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(arr[0], st7 + 3);
            for (i = 0;i < NUM_WORDS; ++i)
            {
                for (j = i+1; j < NUM_WORDS; ++j)
                {
                    if (strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        strcpy(temp, arr[i]);
                        strcpy(arr[i], arr[j]);
                        strcpy(arr[j], temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    } while (s1 = strtok(NULL, ";"));   
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<10;++i) strcpy(arr[i], "");
    char s[] = "s__hello;s__seeyou;s__bye;s__hi";
    add_word(s);
    for(int i=0; i<10;++i) printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bye
hello
hi
seeyou
```

Comment: When you do strcpy(arr[9], st7);
Do you include the s__  ? or the concept is to allow the program to start sorting from bye and not from s__   ?

Comment: @yy123 `strcpy(arr[9], st7);` will include "s__". If you want to exclude "s__" you can do: `strcpy(arr[9], st7+3);`

Comment: Thanks,the output have shown,but the function is not working at all. It is not sorting the strings. The output is just a copy and paste of st7. @4386427

Comment: @yy123 Did you remember to initialize `arr`? How did you initialize it?

Comment: What does your strcpy(arr[i], ""); in this case do? @4386427

Comment: I am trying to integrate it into 1 code instead of a functional code,but whenever,i integrate it together,my output is a blank. I already got a for loop to loop through for the function already,hence,i am utilizing it instead of creating another 'void' for it.

Comment: @yy123 `strcpy(arr[i], "");` is the initialization, i.e. it copies an empty string into the array